# What size should Google TV widgets be?

Tags: widget, google-tv

Does anyone know what size widgets should be for  Google TV?

Comment: Checked this yet? https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_displayguide#Widgets

Comment: Hi, thanks.  Yes I have, and looked at this link too...http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html, but my widget just seems to resize so that  it is cut off. If I reduce the sixe it is too small.  I just want it to fill the space as a nice 9 patch should!

Comment: I tried loading the WeatherListWidget in Android SDK samples on Google TV and it looks okay. Can you please upload a screenshot of how your widget looks on Google TV vs on other Android device.